# Git treats files as unchanged after doing git-add (they disappear from git-status entirely)

Tags: git, eof, eol

I have a file that looks identical to one I want to change it to, but I believe their EOF is different.

I tried to fix git's muckery by adding the following to my `.gitattributes`:

```
* -text -merge -whitespace
```

When I replace the file with the new one, it shows up as an unstaged changed when calling `git status`.

However, when I then do `git add . -f`, they disappear from `git-status` completely. And trying to do `git commit -a` has no effect. It's as if when staging, git decides the files weren't changed after all. (Which I guess is useful, but how can I tell git to not ignore EOF/EOL and such?)

Answer (score 2):

This is normal (albeit frustrating when it is annoying end-of-line issues).

What `git status` does is run *two* `git diff`s.

The first diff is straightforward.  It just compares the `HEAD` commit to the index.  Any differences that show up here are "changes staged for commit": the file in the index differs from the file in the current commit, so there is something new-and-different ready to commit.

The second diff is trickier because Git optimizes.

*In principle*, this second diff is straightforward: it compares the index to the work-tree.  Any differences that show up here are "changes not staged for commit", i.e., you can `git add` the file to copy it *from* the work-tree, *into* the index, replacing any previous version that was in the index.

But, here comes "optimization" and the way it interacts with EOL conversion (and clean filters, if you use those).  Boom, now it's all complicated. :-)

When you set up *either* a clean filter *or* EOL conversions (or both), Git does this cleaning (or converting, which is basically just a pre-programmed form of cleaning) *at the time you run `git add`* to copy the file from the work-tree into the index.  This has two gnarly implications:

1. The file in the index really, literally, *doesn't* match the file in the work-tree, and yet, at this point Git should claim that it *does*.
2. Git doesn't *know*, or for that matter even *care* at this point, what the cleaning did to the file.  All that matters to Git is that the index version is "known to be clean and match the work-tree version", because, well, you just added it, it *must* be clean and match the work-tree version.

(I should mention here the other corollary, which is: when Git is extracting a file *from* the index *to* the work-tree, it applies any "dirtying" smudge filters or EOL conversions at that time.  This means that the work-tree file differs from the index version, and yet, because Git just extracted it, it should be treated as "clean"—or at least, index = work-tree—just as when you `git add` it and it gets cleaned on the way in.)

The primary optimization Git does with index-and-work-tree is to save [stat data](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), particularly the `mtime` (modification time) time-stamp, so that it can tell if you have touched the work-tree version of the file since the last `git add`.  If the saved time stamp and other stat data all match, Git can *assume* that the work-tree version is "clean".

(The file system `stat` operation is slow, so there's yet another optimization: Git saves the *directory* stat data in the index, and can skip `stat`-ing *files within the directory* if the directory mtime itself matches.  Fortunately this is not biting you here.  It's particularly useful with untracked files, using the relatively new "untracked cache".  Not really relevant, just an interesting side note.)

Besides all this, there's one problem with using mtime.  See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/racy-git.txt for details.

The short version of all of this is that sometimes `git status` lies, on purpose.  However, once you have `git add`ed the file, if it is *not* showing up as "staged for commit", the "cleaned" version of the file *is* the same as the one in the `HEAD` (current) commit.

You might want to experiment with `git update-index --refresh` here.  Or, of course, you can `git add` the seemingly-modified files, which takes care of the problem, but is annoying.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! This was really informative.However, my intention is to change the file to the new one, but git is normalizing it, and I don't want that because then the script I have to use that reads from the file doesn't work properly. I was trying to change the file to the new one, but git is treating it as unchanged. So when I cloned on a different computer, I got the old version of the file.

Comment: Given that once you `git add` the file, it's *not* changed, I suspect you have the problem backwards: it's being changed *on the way out*, i.e., when extracted from Git into the work-tree. If you commit your `.gitattributes` update, then the *next* clone will treat it as a non-text file and not modify it on the way out.